# whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'ecommerce/fonts/icofont.eot

Tags: django, heroku, whitenoise

I am trying to deploy my application on Heroku. It was uploaded successfully before, however, I made some changes and I tried re-uploading but it hasn't been responding since then. I keep getting this error: **whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'ecommerce/fonts/icofont.eot' could not be found with .** What can I do about this?

This is the traceback:

```
whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'ecommerce/fonts/icofont.eot' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f73c4861320>.
remote:        The CSS file 'ecommerce/css/icofont.css' references a file which could not be found:
remote:          ecommerce/fonts/icofont.eot
remote:        Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
remote:        relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
remote:        Sentry is attempting to send 0 pending error messages
remote:        Waiting up to 2 seconds
remote:        Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

I have this in my settings.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 14):

This comes late but I hope this will help someone who comes across the issue, at least as a temporary fix:

Using

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

which disables the django caching mechanism, seems to have worked. This error was happening to me even with `WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT = False`

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Answer (score 3):

This code was not working :

```
STORAGES = {
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage", 
    },
}
```

and after I changed it to this :

```
STORAGES = {
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage", 
    },
}
```

And now it is working.